# Styling a custom arrow using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to style this arrow but i have been unable to get this exact style.

[here is image of what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzlAd.jpg)

[here is image of what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgcVB.jpg)

HTML Code:

```
<div className="arrow-div">
      <p>2. Summary</p>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.arrow-div {
width: 209px;
height: 56px;
display: inline-flex;
margin: 54px 10px;
border: 1px solid #d2d6dc;
clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 84% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 9% 53%, 0% 0%);
padding: 18px 3px 18px 32px;
```

}

Comment: Your provided image is not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.arrow-div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.arrow-div:before,
.arrow-div:after {
  content: '';
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 23px;
  width: 132px;
  border-left: 2px solid #0f3c80;
  border-right: 2px solid #0f3c80;
}

.arrow-div:before {
  border-top: 2px solid #0f3c80;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  top: 0;
}

.arrow-div:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0f3c80;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

p {
color: #0f3c80;
```

```html
<div class="arrow-div">
  <p>2. Summary</p>
</div>
```